# How to integrate the function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}e^{tx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

How to integrate the following family of functions? I really do not have too many ideas. The context of this is to find moment generating functions but the context is not too important here.

$$I_n:=\int_{0}^{\infty}n\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}e^{tx}\,dx$$

I wanted to try this inductively/iteratively but I got nowhere (by the way I don't have to do this iteratively).  I should also stress that $\lambda>t$ so that I think $I_n$ converges for each $n$. Could someone please given me  a hint or two? I know how to do $n=1$ btw.

Many thanks!

Comment: One approach is to expand $(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}$ using the binomial theorem, integrate term-by-term, and then (hopefully) re-sum. But that seems rather tedious and so best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets collect the terms first:
$$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}e^{tx}=\lambda e^{-(t-\lambda)x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}$$
$$I_n=n\lambda\int_0^\infty (e^{-x})^{t-\lambda}(1-(e^{-x})^\lambda)^{n-1}dx\tag{1}$$
now if we make the substitution $u=e^{-x}\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{du}{u}$ and our integral becomes:
$$I_n=n\lambda\int_0^1 u^{t-\lambda-1}(1-u^\lambda)^{n-1}$$
now make the substitution $v=u^\lambda\Rightarrow dv=\lambda u^{\lambda-1}du=\lambda v^{(\lambda-1)/\lambda}du\Rightarrow du=\frac{dv}{\lambda}v^{(1-\lambda)/\lambda}$ now sub this in:
$$I_n=n\int_0^1 v^{(t-\lambda-1)/\lambda}\,v^{(1-\lambda)/\lambda}(1-v)^{n-1}dv$$
$$I_n=n\int_0^1 v^{(t-2\lambda)/\lambda}(1-v)^{n-1}dv\tag{2}$$

---

Now, the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) is defined as:
$$B(x;a,b)=\int_0^x y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1}dy\tag{3}$$
and the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is defined as:
$$B(a,b)=\int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\tag{4,5}$$
Your integral fits this form nicely, you could also use binomial expansion.

Comment: ive noticed an error im correcting it now

Comment: A good approach. The change $u=e^{-\lambda{x}}$ leads to the required Beta-function in one step, though.

Comment: @Svyatoslav yep I just wanted to show the kind of steps you can take to recognise an integral than can be represented as a standard function

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the comment, it is actually not too terrible to use binomial theorem. However, first observe that

$$ne^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^n\text{.} $$

Then you can apply binomial theorem to

$$(1-e^{-\lambda x})^n $$

and take the derivative of the resulting sum. Once substituted into the integrand, evaluating the integral (term by term) is straightforward. The result will be a sum of $n$ terms and will not be pretty.

Comment: Good simplification. +1

Answer (score 2):

Using hypergeometric functions$$J=\int\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}e^{tx}\,dx$$
$$J=\frac{\lambda  e^{t x} \left(1-e^{-\lambda  x}\right)^n \left(1-e^{\lambda 
   x}\right)^{-n} \, _2F_1\left(1-n,\frac{t}{\lambda }-n;-n+\frac{t}{\lambda
   }+1;e^{x \lambda }\right)}{\lambda  n-t}$$ if $\Re(t)<\Re(\lambda )\land \Re(\lambda )>0\land \Re(n)>0$
$$K=\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}e^{tx}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (n) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{\lambda }\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{t}{\lambda }+1\right)}$$
$$I_n=n\frac{\Gamma (n) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{t}{\lambda }\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{t}{\lambda }+1\right)}$$

Comment: One also has the (trivial) simplification $n\Gamma(n)=\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for integer $n$.

Comment: @Semiclassical. I did not want to finish

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), its trivial to notice that $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is the PDF and $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ is the CDF. Therefore,
a substitution $u = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ would simplify it.

$$ u = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$$
$$du = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx \tag{1}$$
$$ 1 - u = e^{-\lambda x}$$
$$ \frac{-\ln(1 - u)}{\lambda} = x$$
$$ \frac{-t \hspace{0.05cm} \ln(1 - u)}{\lambda} = tx$$
$$ e^{\frac{-t \hspace{0.05cm} \ln(1 - u)}{\lambda}} = e^{tx}$$
$$ (1 - u)^{\frac{-t}{\lambda}} = e^{tx} \tag{2}$$
Plugging $(1)$ and $(2)$ into this expression,
$$ I_n = \int_0^{\infty} n (1 - e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1} e^{tx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$$
and changing the limits, we get,
$$ I_n = \int_0^{1} n u^{n-1} (1 - u)^{\frac{-t}{\lambda}} dt$$
This can be re-written in terms of the Beta function as follows-
$$ I_n = n \operatorname{B}(n, 1 - \frac{t}{\lambda})$$